# SELECT after createOrReplaceTempView in Foundry's Code Workbook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-workbooks

MRE:

- Created a dataset from Fusion
- Created a transformation in Code Workbook

  ```py
  def unnamed(src):
      src.createOrReplaceTempView('view_src')
      df = spark.sql(f"""SELECT * FROM view_src""")
      return df
  ```

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unnamed", line 1, in <module>
  File "unnamed", line 3, in unnamed
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 649, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 128, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o651.sql.
: com.palantir.foundry.spark.api.errors.DatasetPathNotFoundException: view_src
...
```

How to get back this table as a dataframe from the temp view?

I have also tried `createOrReplaceGlobalTempView`.
In Code Repositories the given code snippet works fine.

Comment: Hi, a lot of the folks from Palantir that regularly answer these questions are on hollidays  till EOY. If no one from the community answers till we're back, we'll drop you an answer then.

Comment: I still haven't solved the problem.

Comment: why do you need the temp view?  I am not super familiar with code workbooks, but I tried to do a `print(spark.catalog.listTables())` with the logic you shared above and it returned an empty list `[]`. My guess is that this is not supported. Code Repositories builds run in dedicated spark driver/executors, while code workbooks (I think) run in warmed up spark nodes so you can have faster response times, thus contain some sandboxing, which would justify why it works on one and not the other.

Comment: Thank you for the insights. Honestly, now I'm just curious of why it's like this. Originally I wanted a build cycle quicker than in repositories to test GROUPING SETS. As they are only supported in SQL, I had to create a view.

Comment: The interesting thing is that if src is created using createDataFrame, the code snippet works. It only fails when src is provided as input.